# curl with table fusion

Tags: curl, google-fusion-tables

when I try to get data from my fusion table, I received from my request string like

```
<! DOCTYPE HTML Public "-//w3c//dtd html final// EN>
<HTML>
<Head>
<style>
a:link {font:....}
a:visited {font:......}
</style>
<meta HTTP-EQUIV="content-type" content="text-html; charset= window....">
```

not like the one I received from java or c# API 
my C code is like that

```
typedef struct pageInfo_t {
char *data;
int  len;
} pageInfo_t;

static size_t HTTPData(void *buffer, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *userData) {
 int len = size * nmemb;
 pageInfo_t *page = (pageInfo_t *)userData;
 if (buffer && page->data && (page->len + len < (16 * 1024)) ) {
   memcpy(&page->data[page->len], buffer, len);
   page->len += len;
 }
 return len;
}

const char urlDataT[]="http://www.google.com/fusiontables/api/query?sql=select * from 3333333";

jstring Java_com_AnalyticToolC_AnalyticToolActivity_JNIGetToken( JNIEnv* env,jobject entryObject)
{
pageInfo_t page;
CURL *curl;
CURLcode res;
char *buffer;


 page.data = (char *)malloc(16 * 1024);
 page.len = 0;
if (page.data)
  memset(page.data, 32, 16 * 1024);

buffer = (char *)malloc(1024);

curl = curl_easy_init();
if(curl) {

 curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, urlDataT);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, HTTPData);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &page);

res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
    /* always cleanup */
curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
if(res == 0) {
  if (buffer) {
    page.data[page.len < 256 ? page.len : 256] = '\0';
sprintf(buffer, "pagedata(%d): %s. done.\n", page.len, page.data);
    return (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, buffer);
  }
}
sprintf(buffer, "Result %d", res);
return (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, buffer);
} else {
   return (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, "Unable to init cURL");
 }
}
```

what should I do to received string contain table data

Answer (score 0):

You need to url encode your request. E.g.

```
 $ curl "http://www.google.com/fusiontables/api/query?sql=select+*+from+3333333"
```

Comment: I solve it just add these two option to curl before perform:
  
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, 1L);
    struct curl_slist *headers = NULL;
    headers = curl_slist_append(headers, "Content-Type: application/atom+xml");
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, headers);

Comment: Sorry, didn't realize java had a curl lib.